# How to copy data from csv file & paste into powerpoint using vba

Tags: vba, excel, automation

I am having problem while copying data from csv file & paste it to power point.
I am successfully doing it while importing excel into power point but having trouble with csv file.

Any suggestion would be very helpful.

Thanks

Comment: Hello,
My problem is solved now.
Solution is : copy the csv file data as we copy excel data i.e. same as by take csv file as a workbook.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Copy the csv file data as we copy excel data 
i.e. Take csv file as a workbook.

Answer (score 0):

@Gazal solved this problem by:

1. Pasting the data into a blank workbook in `Excel`
2. Copying it from `Excel` and pasting it into `Powerpoint`